# RhoConnect-rb High Level Setup Requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rhomobile, rhoconnect

What high level setup is required for RhoConnect if I'm using Rails and the [RhoConnect plugin 'RhoConnect-rb'](http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/4.0.0/rhoconnect/rails-plugin#setup-the-model)?

Specifically,

1. Will I still need a RhoConnect Integration Server?
2. Will I still need to write [source adapters](http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/4.0.0/rhoconnect/source-adapters)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is documented under the introduction section of the plugin section (with diagram).

http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/4.0.0/rhoconnect/plugin-intro

1. Yes - you will still need a RhoConnect Server
2. No - you do not need source adapters